# Rotate before translate or translate before rotate? What difference it makes?

Tags: javascript, html, rotation, translation

I have these two lines in my code being developed in HTML5:

```
context.rotate(radian);
radian += 0.1;
context.translate(128,128);
```

The above result gives a different result the below lines:

```
context.translate(128,128);
context.rotate(radian);
radian += 0.1;
```

What is the difference between these 2 snippets of code? I get different result but why and how calculation differs, I am not able to understand this.

Comment: Try drawing it out on some graph paper and see for yourself what happens. That should help show you which one you want to be using.

Comment: @AndyBursh: Translate and then rotate was simple to understand. But rotation and then translation was tricker to understand. Thanks. Your idea of graph paper really helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is the origin of the transformation. If you perform a translate transform before, perhaps you have to adjust the transform-origin of the following rotate transform, or viceversa. It depends on the results you are trying to achieve.